# How to import a python script which include a library itself to a colab notebook

Tags: python

As an example, I have the following python script which has the numpy library as a dependency.

> import numpy as np
>
> def generate():
>       z = np.zeros(shape=(10, 10))
>       print(z)

I want to import this script into colab note book but it gives the following error.
[image]

I followed the best procedure using the following code.

> import sys  sys.path.append('/content/drive/My Drive/scriptDir')

could anyone explain how to mitigate this problem?

Comment: It seems to be looking for a module called category however I cannot see a reference to this in your code? Is there more code that is not shown in your example?

Comment: Actually the script name was called as category.py.

Comment: This does not explain how this file is being imported or why? If you are already in the file you are trying to import then there is no need to import it again?

Comment: Here the problem is that, when there is no imports in the python script, The file can easily imported to the notebook. But when there is a import statement , the above error occurs.

Comment: When you say "import to the notebook", what are you actually doing? I managed to get your code working in colab.

Comment: I have  a colab notebook and a python script. The python script has numpy as a dependency. I want to use the python script inside the notebook by including it as a  dependency inside the notebook. let ay the python script is named as category.py. the I want to use the script inside the notebook using "Import category". This seems be working when there is no dependency inside the python script but when there is a library as dependency, the above error occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "run" directory is the directory that contains the sample_data folder provided for a new notebook, placing any files needed for import in here will allow them to be imported as seen here,

[image]